# Azure load balancer with two or more VMs having private IP address

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I've created Azure Load balancer and added two VMs to the backend pool but I'm not able to RDP to any of the VMs. I've made the required configuration as mentioned below

Inbound NAT Rules configured on the Load Balancer to allow RDP using custom ports i.e. 3000 (mapped to 3389) for VM1 and 3001 (mapped to 3389) for VM2.

NSG configured to allow inbound connections to port 3389.

NSG is configured at subnet level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've made the required configuration as mentioned below

According to your description, we should check our NSG settings.

1.Please check your **NSG associate with VM interface**, like this:

[image]

If there a NSG associate with it, make sure that NSG allow port 3389 in inbound rules.

2.Check **Azure load balancer NAT rules** settings:

[image]

Please check them, let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Do we really need to attach NSG at the network level as it's already attached at the subnet level?

Comment: No,just to check it exist or not? No NSG for that VM works fine too

Comment: To verify I ran **Verify IP Flow** via Network Watcher on port 3389 for both the VM's and it's accepting the traffic via the rule I've created **RDP-allow** in NSG.

Comment: What is the message when you try to connect it?

Comment: I'm getting standard RDP message. Here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/uihTp

Comment: could  you please associate a public IP to that VM, and use that IP to RDP it?

Comment: OK, I tried it and it's working that way :-). But I don't want to have separate public IP for each of the VM. I want to RDP using load balancer **IP: port ** combination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71108/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-amir).

Comment: could you show you NAT rules here?

Comment: For reference https://imgur.com/a/CKOnL

Comment: @Amir If it helps, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited, thanks. Also if you need more help, please let me know:)